# Do scriptures say anything about dead spirits or ghosts changing into beasts?

Tags: atma, ghosts

I am wondering if scriptures say anything about dead human spirits or ghosts changing into something else after death, or after being dead awhile?

Comment: How can a spirit be dead?

Comment: I added the word human, sorry it was assumed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you want an answer only from the Vedas or Hindu scripture in general?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Simply, the ghost have several types in them according to the Hindu mythology, a spirit would transform into one of these types depending upon the situation in which the person lived and died. For example, if a very intelligent man dies and his soul doesn't attain moksha then he would most probably transform into vetala or the most intelligent ghost of all.